# jQuery/PHP: automatically fill form fields querying MySQL

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I am developing a form with many fields where the first of them is a select menu. I wish that once selected an item from the select menu then a php query to a database is done and, if there are useful information, the following fields should automatically be filled in so that the user can edit them and save. So, is there a way to do that via jQuery?

Comment: downvote for not showing any research effort or what you have tried so far: http://www.mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the first element is a select list, I'd either bind the change or the click event and make an AJAX call to recover the information and then fill my fields accordingly:

```
$("#myList").on("click", function(ev, ui)
{
    $.ajax({
        url: "path/to/my/php/script.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {myValue: ui.value},
        success: my_callback
        });
});

function my_callback($data)
{
    //fill fields with data
}
```

EDIT: The first parameter of my click function is simply an object describing the event. So far as I can tell, every event handler gets it by default. It's used sometimes to stop the propagation with ev.preventDefault()

The second parameter is an object representing the list element that was clicked, thus ui.value should give you the value you just clicked on. However, I'm not entirely certain this parameter exists outside of JQuery UI objects. If it doesn't work, try doing this instead:

```
$("#myList").val()
```

Comment: Fine! I'm gonna try it as soon as I have finished to build the form. Just one thing is not clear to me: what ara the parameters ev and ui? I've just started using jQuery and I really know few things :(

Comment: I edited my answer to explain what the parameters are.

Comment: I corrected a mistake in the Ajax call too, you might want to take a look at it.